# Consider a set equipped with two idempotent functions that commute.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Consider a set $X$ equipped and two functions $f,g : X \rightarrow X$. Assume $f$ and $g$ commute with each other. Finally, call $x \in X$ a fixed point of $f$ iff $f(x)=x.$

Then we can show that if $x$ is a fixed point of $f$, then so too is $g(x)$.

*Proof*. Suppose $f(x)=x$. Then $g(f(x))=g(x)$. So $f(g(x))=g(x)$. So $g(x)$ is a fixed point of $f$.

This is probably a silly question, but if we assume that $f$ and $g$ are idempotent, does the converse necessarily hold?

Comment: Just try $f$ and $g$ to be the same non-identity idempotent map, and you get a counterexample.

Comment: @darijgrinberg, good point. Would you prefer to write an answer yourself, or should I do a community wiki?

Comment: CW is probably best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Consider the three element set $\{ 0,1\}$. Suppose that $f$ and $g$ are both equal to the function taking everything to $0$. Then $g(1)$ is a fixed point of $f$, since $f(g(1))=f(0)=0=g(1)$. However, $1$ is not a fixed point, since $f(1) = 0 \neq 1.$

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer. $f$ is not idempotent in this example, but perhaps we can salvage it?

Comment: @user18921 sorry, that was stupid. It has been edited, I hope it is okay this time!

Comment: @user18921 and I see that it has also been answered in the comments, so apologies again. If you/darij want to answer it I'll remove this, but I'll leave it for now so there is an answer.

Comment: No worries man, yeah this is basically what [darij](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/586/darij-grinberg) was saying. Btw, why not cut it down to two elements? Edit. Nah there's no need to remove it.

Comment: Hey Joe, why not community wiki this.

Comment: @user18921 done :)

Comment: I did an edit, but I'm not sure if its better. Feel free to role it back if you wish.